How to solve $\lfloor x\rfloor^2+\{x\}^2=2x^2$?
How to solve $\lfloor x\rfloor^2 + \{x\}^2 = 2x^2$?
$\lfloor x\rfloor $ is the integer part of $x$ and $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$. I have no idea how to solve this.

I edited your post to use more conventional notation.  Feel free to roll back the changes if you prefer the notation you used.

What's the definition for negative numbers? $[-2.1] = -2$ and ${-2.1}=-0.1$ or$ [-2.1]=-3$ and ${-2.1}=0.9$?

@lulu the original question had the floors and fracs squared

To the question, note that ${x}$ is small, by definition, so if $x$ has any magnitude, the left hand is considerably smaller than the right.

@GeorgeCoote  Yes, thanks.  Corrected.

@GeorgeCoote can you explain why with deleted squares this equation will still be true?

I don't think linear algebra is an appropriate tag here

If $x\ge 0$, then $\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$ and ${x}\le x$, so $\lfloor x\rfloor^2+{x}^2=2x^2$ only if $\lfloor x\rfloor={x}=x$, i.e. $x=0$. So if $x\ne 0$, x must be negative.

Just saying "I have no idea" is typing not well-received here. Even if you really have no effort to show, you should at least say something about where the problem comes from.

As $2x^2 = \lfloor x \rfloor^2 +\{x\}^2 \leqslant x^2 + 2x + 2$ then you must seek for $x \in [1-\sqrt{3}, 1+\sqrt{3}]$.
As stated in the comments, if $x > 0$, then $\lfloor x \rfloor^2 +\{x\}^2 < 2x^2$, so $x$ must be negative.
$x = 0$ is a solution.
This leaves $\lfloor x \rfloor = -1$. The equation then becomes $2x^2 = 1 + (x+1)^2$ that has two real solutions, only one of which has floor -1: $1-\sqrt{3}$.
So $x = 0$ and $x = 1-\sqrt{3}$ are the only solutions.

Try  $x=1-\sqrt 3$, so $\lfloor x \rfloor=-1$ and ${x}=0.267949192=2-\sqrt 3$.  Of course, it all depends on how you define the floor of a negative number.

@lulu I’m not sure I get it : $1 - \sqrt{3}$ is not a solution to the equation, so what to try with it exactly?

With $x=1-\sqrt 3$ we have $\lfloor x \rfloor=-1$ and ${x}\sim .2679$ so the left hand is $1.07179677$.  which is indeed $2x^2$

Thanks, I’ve edited it

Still wrong...if $x=2-2\sqrt 3\approx -1.464101615$ the floor is $-2$ and the fractional part is $4-2\sqrt 3\approx 0.535898385$.  That is another solution.  Again, it depends on how you define these quantities for negative arguments.  I am defining the floor to be the greatest integer which isn't greater than the argument, regardless of sign.  And the fractional part of $x$ is $x-floor(x)$.  Other people use different conventions.

As a general note:  the site prefers that we not answer questions like this one that show no effort or context.  For instance, it would be great if the OP opined on these examples...perhaps they have other conventions in mind. I suggest waiting for them to edit their post.

I have found that $x=2-2\sqrt{3},\ [x]=-2$ and $x=3-3\sqrt{3},\ [x]=-3$ are solutions of the equation left, since when $x<0,\ [x]^2+{x}^2\le x^2-2x+2$ instead of $x^2+2x+2$.
